# Bootstrap confidence intervals for betas in a linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, confidence-interval, lme4-nlme, bootstrap

I am trying to calculate bootstrap intervals for my beta coefficients in linear mixed effect models.
I used the `lme()`function from the `nlme` package. My model looks like this

```
baseline <- lme(rt ~ condition*congruent*type, random= ~1 | id, data= dat, method= "ML")
```

My fixed effects are all two-level factors.

I know how to bootstrap but I am unsure about the random effects structure. Can anyone give me an example with `lme()` or suggest any article/internet page on how to do it?

Thanks a lot!